# Sybase query history?

Tags: sybase

How can I see the query history for Sybase?

I'm using "Sybase Central 16".

I'm looking for something like this for SQL Server:

```
SELECT t.[text] 
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
```

I need to see how my client's application runs queries so I can find some needle-in-a-haystack data tables & columns.

(I'm far from being a Sybase expert. I know SQL Server very well, but I'm doing a consulting job with Sybase).

Thanks.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE, IQ, SQLAnywhere, Advantage)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Sybase ASE, you can pull a good bit of performance related data/metrics from the [MDA (monitoring) tables (master..mon%)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9a57ec3c9937415eb6bf8c5abc91ca86/16.0.3.5/en-US).

Plans and query text can usually be pulled from: `monProcessSQLText` (currently running query), `monSysSQLText` (recently run queries), `monSysPlanText` (query plans for recently run queries).

Keep in mind that the `monSys%` tables are queues, and the volume of data they can maintain will depend on the amount of memory allocated to said queues plus the volume of activity being monitored.

For historical purposes the DBA will typically setup a process to periodically pull data from the MDA tables and store in a repository database from which queries can be run.

There are a handful of 3rd party products on the market that claim to capture/store MDA table though a) you'll need to pay $$ for said product and/or b) the product may not capture/store the data in an easily-accessed format (eg, some products try to rollup the data into summaries ... not very useful if you need to do a deep dive into individual queries).

One **free** product you might want to look at is [ASEMON](https://sourceforge.net/projects/asemon/).  I typically install this product at every client I work for, often times supplanting the expen$sive 3rd party products which tend to spend more effort on summarizing and colorizing the data than in presenting the raw data typically needed for detailed P&T work ... ymmv